# How to update a @Onetomany relation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I don't understand why when I update my parent entity with a @oneToMany relation it sets me to null the id of my child entity?
my 2 entities and controller

Comment: Can you post the code of both entities and the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you need to synchronize both entities. Thats a key thing many forget to implement.
Your `ManyToOne` entity needs to know his parent e.g. the ID of the parent when adding to the parent. Therefore you need to implement a add method to the parent where the `ManyToOne` entity gets his parent "injected.

For example given the following entities

```
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {     
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Childs> childs = new Childs<>();
 
    // This method here is the important part     
    public void addChild(Child child) {
        childs.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}


@Table(name = "child")
public class Child {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_id")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

This is just a simple example containing not other properties, setters, getters and so on for simplicity.

But please post your code to help you with your concrete problem.